# xpath - element is not located even when I construct the xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, selenium-ide

element is not found 
//HTML Code

```
<input type="text" maxlength="61" style="width:185px;" value="" name="name73652d80" onblur="fieldTrack(this);
"/>

input type="text" onblur="fieldTrack(this);" onfocus="javascript:checkFullName(document.forms[0].name73652d80.value);" onclick="javascript:UncheckAllOptions();" maxlength="30" style="width:185px;" value="" name="login73652d80"/>
<br/>
```

// My Selenium code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@type,'text')][starts-with(@name,'name')]")).sendKeys("Mahesh");
```

The above code execute successfully but the below code are fail I did some permutation with contains and starts-with method but its not working

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@type,'text')][contains(@name,'login')])]")).sendKeys("maheshwagh27");
```

Comment: Did you check second input is not a tag. So may be this is issue from UI side.

Answer (score 3):

Here is change that I have made in your code-

are they 2 different textboxes or single one?
If you add screenshot of your textboxes it will clear to all of us-

```
WebElement nameTbox= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@type,'text')][contains(@name,'name73652d80')])]"));
nameTbox.sendKeys("maheshwagh27");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 :**

You are putting extra brackets for this. So remove it:

```
//input[starts-with(@type,'text')][contains(@name,'login')]
```

**Solution 2 :**

You have to use conditions for xpath.

```
//input[starts-with(@type,'text') and contains(@name,'login')]
```

Please let me know If any query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at the second xpath in firepath?

It is a possibility that with the second xpath there are more than one element present on the screen and that's why your webdriver is not able to find the xpath.

I guess the first one will be failing and the second should be passing because you are using @name, 'name' in first but the @name,'login' in second. So the second should be correct.

Comment: Hi, I did both but still my code is fail